# Can TeamCity add the project output to svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, teamcity

Can I get TeamCity to add the project binaries to a svn repository after they have been built? If I need a script, how do I kick it off after a successful build.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building the solution with a script language like Ant, Nant or MsBuild you can tasks or invoke the SVN command line client to commit.

If you don't use a script language, for example a Visual Studio, you can use Artifacts and Artifact Dependencies to create another Build Configuration that runs after a successful build and commits the artifacts. To trigger the second build configuration you can use a Build Dependency Trigger.

If you always want to commit I would say you should keep everything in one single Build Configuration, if you want to commit only in certain cases it may make sense to have 2 Build Configurations with dependencies.